# Mat-tab not underlying when reload

Tags: angular, material-design, mat-tab, reloading

I am using `mat-tab` from Material Design, Angular. When I click on a tab then it becomes `active` and becomes underlined

[image]

However, when I reload the page on the browser, the `active` attribute is still `true` but the underlying is not appearing

[image]

**Would anyone knows how to solve this issue ?**

HTML

```
    <nav mat-tab-nav-bar>

      <!-- About tab -->
      <a mat-tab-link 
         routerLink="{{links[0][1]}}" 
         (click)="activeLink = links[0][0]"
         [active]="activeLink == links[0][0]">
        {{links[0][0]}}
      </a>

      <!-- Revenue tab -->
      <a mat-tab-link 
         routerLink="{{links[1][1]}}" 
         (click)="activeLink = links[1][0]"
         [active]="activeLink == links[1][0]">
        {{links[1][0]}}
      </a>

    </nav>
```

TS

```
export class ProfileHeaderComponent extends SubscriptionContainerComponent implements OnInit {

  user: UserFirestore;
  links = [
    ['A propos', 'about'],
    ['Revenu', 'revenue'],
  ];
  activeLink = this.links[0][0];

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Set user and active link
    this.setUserAndActiveLink();
  }

  setActiveLink(): void {
    const isActiveProfile = this.router.isActive('/home/profile', true);
    const isActiveAbout = this.router.isActive('/home/profile/about', true);
    const isActiveRevenue = this.router.isActive('/home/profile/revenue', true);
    if (isActiveAbout || isActiveProfile) {
      this.activeLink = this.links[0][0];
    } else if (isActiveRevenue) {
      this.activeLink = this.links[1][0];
    } else {
      this.activeLink = undefined;
    }
  }

  setUserAndActiveLink(): void {
    this.subscription.add(
      this.route.data.subscribe((data: { user: UserFirestore }) => {
        // Set user
        this.user = data.user;
        // Set active link
        this.setActiveLink();
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: share code please ?

Comment: This looks like some css Issue. To understand more please share working demo.
You can check given demo url - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-material-tabs

Comment: @Afsar, Piyush thanks for quick support. I updated the issue with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved with

```
// Enable tab underlying on reload
document.body.style.display = "initial";
```

in component constructor